# Showing that two functions defined as limits related to partitions are equal almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

> Given a bounded function $f: [a, b] \rightarrow ℝ$, let $H(x)=\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \sup_{|y-x| \leq \delta} f(y)$, $h(x)=\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \inf_{|y-x| \leq \delta} f(y)$;
>
> $g = \lim g_{P_k}$, where $\{P_k\}$ is a sequence of partitions whose mesh (the maximum over j of the differences of $t_{j-1}$ and $t_j$ for each j) tends to zero and $g_P = \sum_{j=1}^n m_j \chi_{(t_{j-1},t_j]}$; $G = \lim G_{P_k}$ with the same $P_k$ and $G_P = \sum_{j=1}^n M_j \chi_{(t_{j-1},t_j]}$; $M_j$ and $m_j$ are (respectively) the supremum and infimum of f on $[t_{j-1},t_j]$.

I am meant to prove that H = G and h = g, both almost everywhere. I can't think of a good way to come up with a useful measure-zero set on which they disagree, and trying to show that the integral of their difference (i.e., $\int (H-G)dm$) is zero just quickly turns into a mess of notation that I don't know how to translate into an actual computation.

What is the best way to *start* this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard the collection of all partition points  (over all partitions); this is a set of measure zero. Take a point $x$ from the rest, and observe that for each partition we have $t_{j-1}<x<t_j$ for some $j$. Therefore, $M_j\ge H(x)$, because the neighborhoods that $H(x)$ looks at will eventually be contained in $(t_{j-1},t_j)$. Passing to the limit over partitions, we get $G(x)\ge H(x)$. (There is a nontrivial question of *existence* of the limit, but perhaps this was settled elsewhere).

For the reverse inequality, take $\delta$ small enough so that $\sup_{|y-x| \leq \delta} f(y)$ is less than  $H(x)+\epsilon$. Then consider partitions that are sufficiently fine so that the interval containing $x$ lies within $|y-x| \leq \delta$. Then $G(x)\le H(x)+\epsilon$.